Increasing current biases of multistage amplifiers
I remember my professor talking about op amp and he said when we have a multistage amplifier (for instance an op amp) bias current for second stage of amplification must be more than the first stage and so on third more than second why is that? My guess is that it can help linearity of circuit but can anyone describe this in details and effect on stability and noise or any other factor that it would help.

What's the context? When designing a low voltage noise op-amp such statement would be pretty questionable, for example.

Well, slew rate requirements might dictate that the bias current for the second stage be larger than the first (in a Miller dominant pole compensation scheme).  And output current and distortion requirements might dictate that the third stage have higher bias current than the second, but I'm not sure it's a "must have".

You don't say much about the class. And there are so many different kinds of multistage amplifier sections to consider. But taking into account what you were told, I suspect your question comes from the basic bipolar voltage amplifier stage that is taught early. In this case, it's roughly optimal to set the output impedance of a stage equal to its load impedance and take that attenuation hit in order to increase the input impedance of the stage by about $3-4\times$. So then the immediately prior stage's output impedance is $3-4\times$ higher and its quiescent current that much less.

This is only true for non-ideal source impedances driving the system. It is easier to show in a simulation run in Spice than it is to show the math for it. Chain two bipolar stages together, use a 10 k source impedance for the input, a 1 k load impedance at the output, and find the optimal value $x$ such that the output impedance of a stage is $x\times$ its load. The maximal final system gain is achieved at $x\approx 1$, assuming the usual 10% of Iq biasing rule.

Let's assume you are talking about an op-amp intended to be a voltage amplifier, having the following properties in the ideal case:

input impedance is infinite, so input current is zero.
output impedance is zero, so output current can be infinite.
gain is infinite.
bandwidth is infinite.
noise is zero.
power consumption is zero.
offset voltage is zero.  (This can be defined as the output voltage
when input is 0V and gain set to 1 by a feedback loop, but other definitions exist).
cost is zero.

Now, of course, no such op-amp exists, but this is the ideal that all designers strive for.  Let's examine some of these properties (not all, that would take too long):
Property #1: To have high input impedance, we know that the bias current of a transistor amplifier must be as low as possible.  So this means the input stage of the op-amp must have a low bias current.
Property #2: To have low output impedance, we know that the bias current of a transistor amplifier must be as high as possible.  So this means the output stage of the op-amp must have a high bias current.
Property #3 & #4: To have high gain and bandwidth, we know that the bias current of a transistor amplifier must be as high as possible.  So any part of the op-amp that provides the gain (voltage amplification) must have a high bias current.
So, for the input stage, we need a low bias current to achieve property #1.  But we have a problem: we also know that low bias current means this amplifier has a high output impedance, which reduces its ability to drive the next stage.  Now, for the next stage, we want its gain to be as high as possible, which means we need high bias.  However, we know that an amplifier with a high bias has a low input impedance.
So now we have the situation where an amplifier with high output impedance (due to low bias current) drives the input of an amplifier with a low input impedance (due to high bias current), the net gain of the two stages when connected together is reduced from the ideal case.
So, there has to be a compromise: the bias current of each stage must be carefully selected in order to get a good overall result for the entire op-amp, not just an optimum result for each individual section.
To get an overall good result that is a close match for all the ideal properties of an ideal voltage amplifier, this bias current must be low for the input stage, and then get higher for each subsequent stage.


bias current for second stage of amplification must be more than the
first stage and so on third more than second why is that?

I'll try to answer that. I'll be quantitative about it.

My guess is that it can help linearity of circuit but can anyone
describe this in details and effect on stability and noise or any
other factor that it would help.

I can't address stability and noise or any other factor. Way too broad. But I can address the first point, perhaps.
Some assumptions I'll make:

The signal source has a known impedance, \$R_{_\text{SRC}}\$.
The final output load is \$R_{_\text{LOAD}}\$.
There are \$N\$ stages.
Each stage is an NPN bipolar voltage amplification transistor CE stage with emitter degeneration and a single supply rail, \$V_{_\text{CC}}\$. The base biasing pair will be composed of \$R_{_\text{B2}}\$ to ground and \$R_{_\text{B1}}\$ to \$V_{_\text{CC}}\$. The emitter resistor is \$R_{_\text{E}}\$ and the collector resistor is \$R_{_\text{C}}\$.
The biasing pair of resistors will use \$\%_{_\text{BIAS}}\$ of \$I_{_\text{Q}}\$.
The NPN base current is neglected (ideal \$\beta\$) and there's no Early Effect.
The NPN base-emitter voltage is \$V_{_\text{BE}}=700\:\text{mV}\$.
The quiescent collector voltage is \$\%_{_\text{C}}\$ of \$V_{_\text{CC}}\$.
The quiescent emitter voltage is \$\%_{_\text{E}}\$ of \$V_{_\text{CC}}\$.
Each stage presents, to the prior stage, a load of \$x\cdot R_{_\text{SRC}}\$.
Maximum final voltage gain into the load is the goal, solving for \$x\$ to achieve it.
Power into the load is not the goal.

For simplicity (and more derivation is needed to prove this simplification doesn't impact the results), I'll assume that \$R_{_\text{B2}}\$ represents the stage's load as seen by its signal source. And in every stage \$R_{_\text{B2}}\$ of that stage will be set to \$x\times\$ the signal source impedance, which is either \$R_{_\text{C}}\$ of a prior stage or else \$R_{_\text{SRC}}\$ if the stage is the first stage. So the input signal for each stage is always attenuated by \$\frac1{1+\frac1{x}}\$.
Solve:
e1 = Eq( rb2, x*rsrc )                           # set RB2 = x-factor times RSRC
e2 = Eq( rb1, (vcc-vbe-vepct*vcc)/(iq*iqpct) )   # figure out RB1 -- no base current
e3 = Eq( iq, (vbe+vepct*vcc)/rb2/iqpct )         # work out IQ
e4 = Eq( rc, (vcc-vcpct*vcc)/iq )                # work out RC
e5 = Eq( re, vcc*vepct/iq )                      # work out RE
solve( [ e1, e2, e3, e4, e5 ], [ rb1, rb2, rc, re, iq] )[0]
(rsrc*x*(-vbe - vcc*vepct + vcc)/(vbe + vcc*vepct),     # RB1
 rsrc*x,                                                # RB2
 iqpct*rsrc*vcc*x*(1 - vcpct)/(vbe + vcc*vepct),        # RC
 iqpct*rsrc*vcc*vepct*x/(vbe + vcc*vepct),              # RE
 (vbe + vcc*vepct)/(iqpct*rsrc*x))                      # IQ

Also, for each stage, find from \$\frac{R_{_\text{C}}}{R_{_\text{E}}}\$ that the ideal \$A=\frac{1-\%_{_\text{C}}}{\%_{_\text{E}}}\$. That, combined with loaded signal attenuation, means that each stage contributes a net (non-ideal) gain of \$A_v=\frac{1-\%_{_\text{C}}}{\%_{_\text{E}}\,\cdot\,\left(1+\frac1{x}\right)}\$. And there will be a final attenuation due to the impact of \$R_{_\text{LOAD}}\$ on the final stage's collector impedance, which is:
$$\frac1{1+\frac{R_{_\text{SRC}}}{R_{_\text{LOAD}}}\cdot\left(x\,\cdot\,\%_{_\text{BIAS}}\,\cdot\,V_{_\text{CC}}\cdot\frac{1 - \%_{_\text{C}}}{V_{_\text{BE}} + V_{_\text{CC}}\,\%_{_\text{E}}}\right)^N}$$
So the total system gain is:
$$A_v=\frac{\left[\frac{1-\%_{_\text{C}}}{\%_{_\text{E}}\,\cdot\,\left(1+\frac1{x}\right)}\right]^N}{1+\frac{R_{_\text{SRC}}}{R_{_\text{LOAD}}}\cdot\left[x\,\cdot\,\%_{_\text{BIAS}}\,\cdot\,V_{_\text{CC}}\cdot\frac{1 - \%_{_\text{C}}}{V_{_\text{BE}} + V_{_\text{CC}}\,\%_{_\text{E}}}\right]^N}$$
That is the value to be maximized by adjusting \$x\$. So the differential of that is set to zero and solved.
Suppose \$R_{_\text{SRC}}=10\:\text{k}\Omega\$, \$R_{_\text{LOAD}}=1\:\text{k}\Omega\$, \$N=2\$, \$V_{_\text{CC}}=10\:\text{V}\$, \$\%_{_\text{BIAS}}=0.1\$, \$\%_{_\text{C}}=0.5\$, \$\%_{_\text{E}}=0.1\$, and \$V_{_\text{BE}}=700\:\text{mV}\$.
rc1 = iqpct*rsrc*vcc*x*(1 - vcpct)/(vbe + vcc*vepct)
re1 = iqpct*rsrc*vcc*vepct*x/(vbe + vcc*vepct)
av1 = simplify( (rc1/re1) / (1+1/x) )
atten = 1/(1+rsrc/rload*(x*iqpct*vcc*(1-vcpct)/(vbe+vcc*vepct))**N)
for i in solve( Eq( diff(av2**N*atten,x), 0 ), x ):
    i.subs( { vcc:10, iqpct:.1, rload:1e3, rsrc:10e3, vepct:.1, vcpct:.5, vbe:.7, N:2 })
1.07517440445725*I
1.04950846229763

This means that:
(rsrc/rc1).subs( { vcc:10, iqpct:.1, vepct:.1, vcpct:.5, vbe:.7, x:1.04950846229763 })
3.23961180127750

That's the needed increase in quiescent current, from prior stage to following stage, in order to maximize the voltage gain of the system, given the source to load ratio for the system of 10:1. The overall voltage gain would ideally be about:
(av2**N*atten).subs({vcc:10,iqpct:.1,rload:1e3,rsrc:10e3,vepct:.1,vcpct:.5,vbe:.7,N:2,x:1.04950846229763})
3.35697954716352

But I've neglected additional loading due to the other base resistor, the impact of emitter loading on the base, and of course \$r_e^{\:'}\$. Among other details. So the simulator would show a lower result. Each voltage gain stage would probably be about 10% to 20% worse than predicted. And these would add up to a poorer result in simulation.
None of that changes the optimization of \$x\$, though. Even with the lower actual gain, moving \$x\$ in either direction away from optimal will lower the system gain.
Okay. I've held short of using the simulator for this. May as well get the bad news out of the way and see if I can make sense of the results.

That shows a gain of about \$10^{^\frac{7.698}{20}}\approx 2.43\$. Predicted gain was 3.24, but I already knew that would be high. Putting in a fudge factor of 17.5% (which isn't surprising) gives the right result:
((av2/1.175)**N*atten).subs({vcc:10,iqpct:.1,rload:1e3,rsrc:10e3,vepct:.1,vcpct:.5,vbe:.7,N:2,x:1.04950846229763})
2.43149265525651

So known, unaccounted loading is the culprit.
A side detail is that LTspice found the optimal \$x\$ is \$x\approx 1.15\$ rather than \$x\approx 1.05\$ that I computed. But \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$ differences from simulation would easily explain this.
So this suggests another test to validate what's been written so far. I'll reduce the source impedance by a factor of 4 and perform these calculations again:
for i in solve(Eq(diff(av2**N*atten,x),0),x):i.subs({vcc:10,iqpct:.1,rload:1e3,rsrc:2.5e3,vepct:.1,vcpct:.5,vbe:.7,N:2})
2.1503488089145*I
1.66599083710079
(av2**N*atten).subs({vcc:10,iqpct:.1,rload:1e3,rsrc:2.5e3,vepct:.1,vcpct:.5,vbe:.7,N:2,x:1.66599083710079})
6.10073101074151

Here's the spice run:

The gain is about 4.65 and the optimal \$x\$ is \$x=1.83\$. Close enough, considering what's been left out.
The bottom line is that for this kind of bipolar CE stage you gradually need to increase the quiescent current as you move across the stages, from input towards output, in order to get the largest voltage gain as seen by the load. Each successive stage is a little hotter than the prior stage.

If you're talking about a multistage amplifier with little or no local feedback in each stage, namely degeneration, because it is meant to be used with overall negative feedback, then I can agree with your professor's statement about the 3rd stage being the largest bias current, but the 1st and 2nd not really, and it is highly dependent on the application.
Typically, any op-amp uses a very big input stage to minimize input-referred noise. It is relatively simple to simulate an input stage around a feedback loop while sweeping the input bias current and look for the optimum (lowest) input-referred noise.
The 3rd stage having the largest bias current of all 3 stages I can also agree with, as, assuming it's a class-A amplifier, the output stage must be able to drive large loads. If you use a class-AB amplifier, you could use smaller currents. But anyhow, this bias current is always dictated by the kind of load you're supposed to be driving.
The 2nd stage is trickier. Depending on how big the 3rd stage is, the 2nd can be either larger or smaller than the 1st stage's bias current. You can imagine that a larger 3rd stage requires a larger bias current from the 2nd stage to be able to drive it, otherwise you're small-signal 2nd-stage gain might be very poor contributing little to your overall open-loop gain.
All in all, don't take your professor's statements literally, as it all always depends on your specifications. I have worked in IC designs where the input stage was easily 1/3rd of the entire amplifier (including feedback network and extra circuitry around) because of how tight the input-referred noise was, and thus it actually used a higher bias current than that of the 2nd and 3rd stage, because the load of the amplifier was also high impedance.
